# How to highlight language abilities in cover letter for a scientific research position?

Tags: language, application-cover-letter

I'm applying for a scientific research position at a Welsh university and one of the desirable skills is to demonstrate an understanding of the bilingual nature of the University.

As I am fluent in Welsh, I would like to add a sentence to my cover letter stating that I am a bilingual. I would like to write something that makes them feel that it is important to have someone that can speak Welsh and that this would benefit the university.

Can anyone suggest an appropriate sentence to include?

Comment: Do you attach a CV? Would you consider putting it in the CV as sufficient?

Comment: I have already included this info in my CV but was hoping of making it stand out more in the cover letter.

Comment: Maybe mention that you have Welsh roots, which is one of the motivations to study there?

Comment: I don't know if it's appropriate in Welsh culture, but maybe nothing indicates your understanding of bilingualism more clearly than including two cover letters, one in English and the other in Welsh. It'd be perfect if the latter isn't a "translation" and follows a common style for cover letters in Welsh (i.e., it looks and sounds like a native speaker of Welsh wrote for other native speakers).

Comment: "makes them feel that it is important to have someone that can speak Welsh" -- if Welsh is listed by them as a desirable skill, why do you have to make them feel it? Don't they already think it's important? If so then your job is just to let them know you have fluent Welsh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To address your specific question, I would propose the following sentence for your letter (or something similar to your liking) to highlight your language skills. I would position it toward the bottom, in the concluding paragraph:

> I also believe that my fluency in Welsh will contribute to my ability
>   to effectively support the university's bilingual nature.

(alternative wording):

> ...the university's mission of bilingual service.

I would not worry about providing any additional evidence of Welsh proficiency (as a letter written in the language) as you only want to submit the exact documents required in the application, nothing more. If there will be any need to ascertain your language ability, it can be easily done in a quick chat as part of your interview process or by phone.

Good luck!

Comment: Depending how committed they are to bilingual service, I wonder whether you'd have the option of writing the cover letter *only* in Welsh. I don't know what's common in Welsh universities, but they might be set up to translate internally as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I would go beyond what Aymor said and write a paragraph of your cover letter in Welsh where you discuss the importantance of the bilingual philosophy.  Stating you are fluent is quite different than demonstrating it.